# Sequelize transaction method not being called

Tags: javascript, express, web, transactions, sequelize.js

I am new to express/node and using Sequelize as the ORM.

I am attempting to create a listing and then once the listing has been created I would like to update the item.isListed boolean in the item table however I am struggling to get the transaction method to be called - can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with this piece of code?

**/api/listing**

```
var models = require('../../models');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.route('/:id')

    .post(function(req,res){


        models.Item.findOne({
            where : {
                itemID : req.params.id
            }
        }).then(function(item){
            if (item){
                if (item.owner != req.decoded.user.username){
                    res.json({message:"not your item"})
                } else {

                    //This message is displayed in console.
                    console.log("entering transaction");

                    return models.db.sequelize.transaction(function(t){

                        //This message is not displayed in console.
                        console.log("inside transaction")

                        return models.Listing.create({
                            sellerID : req.decoded.user.username,
                            startDate : req.body.startDate,
                            endDate : req.body.endDate,
                            startPrice : req.body.startDate,
                            reservePrice : req.body.reservePrice,
                            isSold : 0,
                            itemID : req.params.id
                        }, {transaction: t}).then(function(t){
                            return item.updateAttributes({
                                isListed : 1
                            }, {transaction: t});
                        })
                    }).then(function(result){
                        res.json({message:"success"})
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        res.json(err);
                    })






                //end of else block 
                }
            //end of if item block  
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.json(err);
        })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: "Struggling to get the transaction method to be called", so what happens exactly? No execution at all or executed partly? Any errors?

Comment: no execution at all - I added a console.log in there to try and see if anything happens but all that gets returned it an empty object '{}'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it

```
return models.db.sequelize.transaction(function(...
```

When you have a chain of promises you need to return every promise or else execution will simply continue without waiting. It would be helpful to know where you added console.log() and what you are logging.

Another thing that might make your code a little more readable and easier to debug is how you update item. Since you have a reference to item you can update like this

```
return item.updateAttributes({isListed: 1}, {transaction: t});
```

```js
return models.Listing.create({
  sellerID : req.decoded.user.username,
  startDate : req.body.startDate,
  endDate : req.body.endDate,
  startPrice : req.body.startDate,
  reservePrice : req.body.reservePrice,
  isSold : 0,
  itemID : req.params.id
}, {transaction: t})
.then(function(t){
  return item.updateAttributes({
    isListed : 1
  }, {transaction: t});
})
```

In this snippet you have `then(function(t) {...` which is overwriting the original transaction object. What is returned is actually the newly created listing. I can't remember if that was there before you edited your question, but it could be the source of the problem.

Comment: I've added your first suggestion - I am still just receiving {} as a response and no alteration to the listing or item table.

Comment: Try  `return models.sequelize.transaction(function(...`  I don't know how you are initializing `models` but I am guessing you are using the suggested boilerplate (from [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/)), in which case sequelize is directly a property of models. One technique I have found useful is to open a node REPL and require your models into that. Then you can use tab completion to determine what properties are connected.

It would also be helpful if you piped the log output from sequelize to a file so you could review the SQL being executed.

Comment: I also added some comments at the end of my answer. Take a look at whether you are overwriting the transaction object and whether that is causing it to fail.